# Reading and comparing column in .txt file in bash

Tags: linux, bash

### I got .txt file which its content is

5742060626,Ms.Pimpan Tantivaravong,Female

5742065826,Ms.Kaotip Tanti,Female

-
I create an interface script to add list in this file
First, I have to compare the input id with the exitsting id in a list.
I use cut command to read only 1st column of .txt file.
But,I got a problem when I am trying to compare it.

Here is my code.

-

```
!/bin/bash
#
datafile='student-2603385.txt'

while read p;
do

if [ "$id" == (echo $p | cut -d, -f1) ]

then
echo 'duplicate id'

fi
done <$datafile
```

-

could anyone suggest me, how should I do?
Thank you

Comment: This looks a little jumbled.  I think you want to assign something to `$id` (the result of your `cut`) and then compare that to `$p`... or to every row?  Could you do what you want by adding the id to the file and then using cut, sort, and uniq?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Your script has numerous quoting bugs, always quote variable expansion when the variable contains a file name, it is also expected when you want to avoid word splitting and pathname expansion by shell.

Letting that aside, in `if [ "$id" == (echo $p | cut -d, -f1) ]`:

- You need command substitution, `$()` around `echo ... | cut ...`, not a subshell `()`
- you also need quotes around `$()` to prevent word splitting (and pathname expansion)
- `==` is bash-ism, not defined by POSIX, just a reminder
- try to use `[[` as much as possible, being a shell keyword `[[` handles word splitting

So with `test` (`[`):

```
if [ "$id" == "$(echo "$p" | cut -d, -f1)" ]
```

better:

```
if [[ $id == $(echo "$p" | cut -d, -f1) ]]
```